# ebay addItem fails because of account type issue

Tags: ebay-api

I am working on example of ebay addItem API, but it fails with following error:

**eBay returned the following error(s):**

> 21532 : You have not specified in my eBay whether you are a private or
>   business seller. You have not specified in my eBay whether you are a
>   private or business seller. Your selling privileges will be suspended
>   until you specify your account type. Please update your registration
>   data in my eBay.

I have also read API docs and followed steps for specifying account type but it doesn't work. Also I have written [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981271/link-my-sandbox-paypal-account-with-ebay-sandbox-store) for that but did not get any solution!

Answer (score 0):

When you create an account on eBay that is used for selling you need to tell eBay whether you are a private or business seller. You need to log into eBay and tell them which one the account is for. Once you have done that the restrictions should be removed.